# Sketchup ruby translate, rotate, scale

Tags: ruby, math, graphics, 3d, sketchup

I am developing plugin to load multiple bojects to model and performing multiple transformations
I am working almost one week i go through sketchucation, sketchup ruby documentation, transformation matrices topics etc and i cannot figure what i am doing wrong.
I am 100% sure that scalling and translating works, but i dont know what about rotations, basiaclly i want to rotate given object around axis.
I would really appreciate any kind of professional ruby plugin makers help!!!
My target is to achieve such component:
[image]

but my current result is:

[image: result]

My code is here, i know it is not shortest:

```
#1)Scale
    scale_transformation = Geom::Transformation.scaling(@transform.scale_vector[0], 
                                                        @transform.scale_vector[1], 
                                                        @transform.scale_vector[2])                                                                                                                                            
    #2)Rotate 
    vector = Geom::Vector3d.new(1, 0, 0)#x axis
    rotate_transformation_x = Geom::Transformation.rotation(@transform.transformation.origin, vector, @transform.rotation_vector[0].degrees)#degrees->radians
    vector = Geom::Vector3d.new(0, 1, 0)#y axis
    rotate_transformation_y = Geom::Transformation.rotation(@transform.transformation.origin, vector, @transform.rotation_vector[1].degrees)#degrees->radians
    vector = Geom::Vector3d.new(0, 0, 1)#z axis
    rotate_transformation_z = Geom::Transformation.rotation(@transform.transformation.origin, vector, @transform.rotation_vector[2].degrees)#degrees->radians

    #if rotate is [0, 0, 0] than rotate transformation is identity matrix:
    if(@transform.rotation_vector[0] == 0 )
        rotate_transformation_x = Geom::Transformation.new()
    end
    if(@transform.rotation_vector[1] == 0 )
        rotate_transformation_y = Geom::Transformation.new()
    end
    if(@transform.rotation_vector[2] == 0 ) 
        rotate_transformation_z = Geom::Transformation.new()
    end
    rotate_transformation = rotate_transformation_x * rotate_transformation_y * rotate_transformation_z

    #3)Translate        
    translate_transformation = Geom::Transformation.translation(Geom::Vector3d.new(
                                                                            meters_to_inches(@transform.translation_vector[0]),
                                                                            meters_to_inches(@transform.translation_vector[1]),
                                                                            meters_to_inches(@transform.translation_vector[2])
                                                                            ))
    #if translate is [0, 0, 0] than translate transformation is identity matrix:
    if(@transform.translation_vector[0] == 0 && @transform.translation_vector[1] == 0 && @transform.translation_vector[2] == 0 )
        translate_transformation = Geom::Transformation.new()
    end
    #using overloaded operator '*' for matrixes

    puts @path + "\r\nFROM PARENT : " + @transform.to_s + ", matrix = " + @transform.transformation.to_a.each_slice(4).inject { |str, row| "#{str}\r\n#{row}" }
    @transform.transformation = (translate_transformation * rotate_transformation * scale_transformation) * @transform.transformation
```

@transform.transformation if there was not previous transformation is identity matrix.
I think my mistake can be connected with order of multiplying matrices
THANK YOU FOR ANY KIND OF HELP!!!

rotation and translation definition are as follows(for example):
[image]

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Could you give examples with a simple object, a rotation definition, what you expect and what you get? Complete Ruby code would also be helpful in order to test it.

Comment: i added sample transform definition, object is described by component tree, each child inherits transform from parent, i think i am close, but i cannot figure if my rotations are OK ;/,, i am expecting result image showed above and i am getting something which is close...

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the setup before you start transforming? Can you provide a snipped that is self-contained? The current one contain a number of variables that isn't defined and hence hard for us to guess exactly what they are. You mention "i want to rotate given object around axis" - can we focus on that perhaps? What axis? What object?